# How to import a Makefile-based project filesystem to Eclipse based ARM DS-5 Workbench?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, arm, project, ds-5

We have an ARM project comprised of dozens of C source and header files, built from CLI using a Makefile hierarchy (specific build options are given as make command line params). The dev environment is the ARM DS-5 toolset. I want to use the existing Eclipse based Workbench IDE to continue the development of the project.

By defining a new Workspace and creating a new C project in it, I can import the whole filesystem to the project to browse and edit the files. However, the IDE is not "aware" of the project structure.

**Is there a way to automatically generate an IDE project based on the project's Makefile(s)?**

Note that there are a few similar questions around here, but I could not find a discussion specific to DS-5, and it looks like some options from CDT are not available in DS-5.